# WPF button click and command doesn't work together MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing some wpf application, using mvvm. I'm trying to use button click event and command together but command never get executed. Also when I use only command without click event it works perfect. Here is the code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="reminderDataTemplate">          
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="150" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="New reminder:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ReminderText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Height="150" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Button Name="btnSaveReminder" Grid.Row="2" Content="Save" Width="auto" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnSaveReminder_Click"  Command="{Binding Path= btnSaveReminder}"  />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Why is this happening?

Just to mention that I must use click and command together becouse my view and viewmodel are in different projects.

**UPDATE:**
Also to say that, when I use click and command together in buttons outside of control template, everything works perfect.

Comment: Tried removing the code >Click="btnSaveReminder_Click"<?

Comment: yes, when I remove it the command executes well. But I need both, the click event and command to get executed.

Comment: *I must use click and command together becouse my view and viewmodel are in different projects*... views and view models are often in different projects but that doesn't explain why you need to use both... what are you doing in your `Click` handler?

Comment: Structure of my application doesn't allow me to add reference of my wpf project to my MVVM project, so I can't access my wpf components from mvvm. I use click event only to change the control template of some listbox, and command is used to save some data into db.

Comment: @Stojdza neither should it. The ViewModel should have no knowledge of the View at all. *Does* your ViewModel have a ICommand-derived property called `btnSaveReminder`? Which framework are you using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

on the `Click event`, execute command.

```
private void btnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    btn.Command.Execute(btn.CommandParameter);
}
```

Comment: Better to check `CanExecute()` before calling `Execute()`.  Note that if your command might ever unavailable, you should verify that the button is still being enabled/disabled based on the command status.  If the command doesn't execute as expected in combination `Click`, the button status may not update correctly either.